# Accuracy is not increasing in images classification when using TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-classification

At my job Interview yesterday, I was asked to build a neural network using TesnorFlow in python to classify images from the flowers images dataset.

But even though it should've worked theoretically, for some reason I couldn't increase the accuracy above 20s%.

> Python Version: 3.8.13
> TensorFlow Versioin: 2.4.1

The data preprocessing methods from the interviewer were given as follows:

```
# create datase
IMG_SIZE = 160
BATCH_SIZE = 32
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
def _parse_data(x,y):
  image = tf.io.read_file(x)  
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3) 
  image = tf.cast(image, dtype=tf.float32)
  image = tf.math.l2_normalize(image)
  
  image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
  return image,y
 
def _input_fn(x,y):
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y))
  ds = ds.map(_parse_data)
  ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=data_size)
  ds = ds.repeat()   
  ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)    
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)   
  return ds

train_ds = _input_fn(x_train, y_train)
validation_ds = _input_fn(x_valid, y_valid)
```

With both training and validation datasets being

> <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((None, 160, 160, 3), (None,)), types:
> (tf.float32, tf.int32)>

With the network being as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models

model_seq = models.Sequential()
    model_seq.add(layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal",input_shape=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,3)))
    model_seq.add(layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2))
    model_seq.add(layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255))
    model_seq.add(layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model_seq.add(layers.MaxPooling2D())
    model_seq.add(layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model_seq.add(layers.MaxPooling2D())
    model_seq.add(layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model_seq.add(layers.MaxPooling2D())
    model_seq.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model_seq.add(layers.Flatten())
    model_seq.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model_seq.add(layers.Dense(len(label_names), activation='softmax'))
    model_seq.summary()
```

The output layer being the only thing that isn't allowed to be change.

> model_seq.add(layers.Dense(len(label_names), activation='softmax'))

(Please note I was for some reason asked to use **model_seq.add()**, and even though it could be triggering for some of you, please ignore it this once :) )

For compiling the model, I used the following:

```
model_seq.compile(optimizer="Adam",
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And for fitting the model:

```
history = model_seq.fit(train_ds,epochs=20,
                        validation_data = validation_ds,
                        steps_per_epoch=100,validation_steps=100)
```

The things I've tried:

1. Using different Augmentation methods (or removing the whole section
   from the network).
2. Changing the Batch and Image sizes.
3. Using Dropout layers.
4. Using early stopping as follows:

   ```
   callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
       monitor='val_loss', 
       min_delta=0, patience=3, verbose=0, 
       mode='auto',baseline=None, 
       restore_best_weights=True)

   history = model_seq.fit(train_ds,epochs=20,
                           validation_data = validation_ds,
                           steps_per_epoch=100,validation_steps=100,
                           callbacks = [callback])
   ```

Yet despite all of the above, I couldn't get any results. Since I couldn't find out what I did wrong exactly, I'm hoping someone here could tell me, so I could learn from this experience.
(Please take into consideration that I wasn't allowed to change the preprocessing functions, with the parameters **IMG_SIZE** and **BATCH_SIZE** being the only exception).

Comment: Do you want another solution without your code but on tensorflow?

Comment: Tbh at this point anything would be appreciated.
Another solution, some hints, or even telling me what i did wrong would be fine. :)

Comment: One mistake I can see is that you're augmenting data for both train and validation data, which you are not supposed to do. Do it only for the train data.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but here is an article that might be of use to you https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn

Comment: @VishalBalaji could you maybe tell me where exactly? Because for some reason, i don't seem to see it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EliasALICHE Thanks for the link !! I didn't know you could test a neural network, i'll make sure to try it ! :)

Comment: @VirgalK, did you try to use `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()`?, from the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy), `from_logits=True` is used when `y_pred` is a logits tensor. The output of the [softmax](https://keras.io/api/layers/activations/#softmax-function) layer is not a logits tensor.

Comment: @VirgalK Comments are not conducive to this, but you've defined some flipping and rotation at the start of `model_seq`. This is applied to both the train and the val data. You're supposed to do augmentation only for train data. I also noticed that you're doing some normalization when you're getting the image itself with `tf.math.l2_normalize`. You are again rescaling with `1/255.` inside your model. Not sure how exactly this will affect your model because I haven't done it before, but this is something you should definitely look into.

Comment: @IranRibeiro I actually did use it from the docs as a force of habit.
Do you reckon that removing it would be enough, or should I go for another loss?

Comment: @VishalBalaji oh now i see it!
I'll try to fix it !! Thanks again !

Comment: I think removing the `from_logits=True` part it will do it. But you should try to do what @VishalBalaji said, too.

Comment: Yes, from_logits=True is incorrect in this case

Answer (score 1):

**“TLDR: If you want to use their preprocessing part and don't change anything go to First Approach. If you want to augment images, Go to Second Approach and use [ImageDataGenerator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)”.**

**First Approach**
As you say: `I had to use the preprocessing functions and don't change this` and because I don't access your data, I use `cifar10` dataset and use your preprocessing part. (only line of reading from file changed).

1. Because you shouldn't change **`IMG_SIZE=160`** in the preprocessing part, I add this layer : `tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize(image, (32, 32))))` to the network because working with large images causes a crash.
2. You don't need a very large network, first check with a small network then step by step add parameters then add layers.

We can get a better result like the below: *(On `cifar10` with your network I get 10% accuracy like you.)*

```
import tensorflow as tf
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# create datase
IMG_SIZE = 160
BATCH_SIZE = 32
data_size = 32
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
def _parse_data(x,y):
#   image = tf.io.read_file(x) <- because don't read from path 
  image = x
#   image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3) <- because don't read from path and don't have jpeg
  image = tf.cast(image, dtype=tf.float32)
  image = tf.math.l2_normalize(image)

  image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
  return image,y

def _input_fn(x,y):
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y))
  ds = ds.map(_parse_data)
  ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=data_size)
  ds = ds.repeat()   
  ds = ds.batch(BATCH_SIZE)    
  ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)   
  return ds

train_ds = _input_fn(X_train, y_train)
validation_ds = _input_fn(X_test, y_test) 

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.Input(shape=(160, 160, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize(image, (32, 32))),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50,activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax')

])

model.compile(optimizer="Adam",
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_ds,epochs=4,
                        validation_data = validation_ds,
                        steps_per_epoch=100,validation_steps=100)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/4
100/100 [==============================] - 8s 38ms/step - loss: 2.2445 - accuracy: 0.1375 - val_loss: 2.1406 - val_accuracy: 0.2138
Epoch 2/4
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 33ms/step - loss: 2.0552 - accuracy: 0.2688 - val_loss: 1.9764 - val_accuracy: 0.3250
Epoch 3/4
100/100 [==============================] - 4s 38ms/step - loss: 1.9468 - accuracy: 0.3022 - val_loss: 1.9014 - val_accuracy: 0.3200
Epoch 4/4
100/100 [==============================] - 4s 36ms/step - loss: 1.8936 - accuracy: 0.3341 - val_loss: 1.8883 - val_accuracy: 0.3419
```

**Second Approach:** Augment images with [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator):

```
import tensorflow as tf

flowers = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
    'flower_photos',
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz',
    untar=True)


data_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255, 
    rotation_range = 10,    # Degree range for random rotations.
    horizontal_flip = True, # Randomly flip inputs horizontally.
    vertical_flip = True,   # Randomly flip inputs vertically.
    )
    
imgs_dataset = data_gen.flow_from_directory(flowers, class_mode='categorical', 
                                            target_size=(160, 160), batch_size=32,
                                            shuffle=True)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=(3,3),input_shape=(160, 160, 3),activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(50,activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5,activation='softmax')

])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(imgs_dataset,epochs=5)
```

Output:

```
Found 3670 images belonging to 5 classes.
Epoch 1/5
115/115 [==============================] - 39s 311ms/step - loss: 1.7904 - accuracy: 0.4161
Epoch 2/5
115/115 [==============================] - 27s 236ms/step - loss: 1.0878 - accuracy: 0.5605
Epoch 3/5
115/115 [==============================] - 28s 244ms/step - loss: 1.0252 - accuracy: 0.6005
Epoch 4/5
115/115 [==============================] - 27s 233ms/step - loss: 0.9735 - accuracy: 0.6196
Epoch 5/5
115/115 [==============================] - 29s 248ms/step - loss: 0.9313 - accuracy: 0.6455
```

Comment: I usually do use the ImageDataGenerator but unfortunately as I stated in the question during this interview I had to use the preprocessing functions given and only build a network that would work with them :(

Comment: @VirgalK, OK No problem, I will send another approach with preprocessing of you

Comment: Do they give you a dataset??

Comment: @l'mahdi yes the data set consist of 2 columns first one being the image path second being the class
The image path is then processed through _parse_data() into an image tensor that is used to create the dataset

Comment: I know, because I see this: `tf.io.read_file(x)`,  then how do we run your code? without having image and path

Comment: @VirgalK, where is this code of question you write and you want edit this to get better result?

Comment: that's a good question. The dataset used is the same flowers one you're using, and they just extracted it locally and loaded it.
Unfortunately, I don't have the data because they were provided in the interview, but I believe just extracting the same dataset you're using ant iterating over the folder using blob would give the same dataset.

Comment: @VirgalK, I add the first approach with your preprocessing part, please check this. Do you get a better result?